# Showing history on a text based interactive adventure game in Java

Tags: java, game-center

Hello I am making a text based adventure game similar to Dark Room http://adarkroom.doublespeakgames.com/ [image]

The problem is I have no idea how to make the history like in the picture also some insight into the opacity would be useful.

Comment: You want to develop a web game, or desktop game?

Comment: @waltersu it is a standalone game project on the destop

Comment: Do you want to know about the physical mechanisms of maintains a history or do you want to know how you might display it?

Comment: Both @MadProgrammer

Comment: The first is nothing more exciting the a List of some kind, the second will depend on its the framework you want to use

Comment: Yes but how would i display it @MadProgrammer

Comment: That depends on which GUI framework you intend to use

Comment: Can you provide me an example on how to do it because i really have no idea @MadProgrammer

Comment: [How to use lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and/or [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)